# DNS A record wildcard priority

Tags: dns, wildcard-subdomain

If I have a wildcard DNS entry:

```
*.mydomain.com => 1.2.3.4
```

And another standard A record:

```
foo.mydomain.com => 7.6.5.4
```

Which record takes priority? Is there a way to force the `foo` A record to take priority and only fallback to the wildcard if no A record exists?

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [su]

Answer (score 6):

The wildcard will apply only to names in the zone which aren't listed in the DNS at all.

So the wildcard is not applied to any explicitly defined subdomain (same applies for MX records).